# How to get a transfer function from a Simulink model into Matlab

Tags: matlab, simulink

I would like to plot a transfer function from a Simulnik file model.mdl where I used blocks From Workspace (simin) and To Workspace (simou) to start a simulation from Matlab.

And now comes the problem. I simply can't find a way to run this Simulink model in Matlab.

Here is my code;

```
sim('model');  


h=simout/simin;

[H,omega]=freqz(h);
%plot
```

I get this errors;

```
Error evaluating parameter 'VariableName' in 'model/From
Workspace'

Caused by:
    Error using sigma (line 8)
    Undefined function or variable 'simin'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

This is my model:
[image]

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you actually know the transfer function? Is implemented correctly in Simulink? Then the error suggests that you haven't assigned the correct variable name to your from workspace block, you just kept the default `VariableName`. For the frequency response you need to define your transfer function outside Simulink with `tf`, then use `bodeplot` to plot it.
(Look at the end of these answer)

---

But it appears to me, that you have some **inputdata** and some **outputdata** and you'd like to **estimate the transfer function** and finally get the frequency response of that transfer function. There is no need for Simulink to do that. Once you found your transfer function you could implement it into Simulink using the `Transfer function` block, feed the simulation with the `From Workspace` Block and display the results with `Scope`. But first you need the transfer function.

Assuming you have the variables `inputdata` and `outputdata` you first need to create a transfer function dataset:

```
% prepare data for tftest, 100 is a random chosen sampling time
tfdata = iddata(data(:,1),data(:,2),100);
```

then you can use `tfest` to estimate the transfer function with a chosen number of poles:

```
N = 5;     % Number of poles
sys = tfest(tfdata,N);
```

The frequency response you get e.g. with `bodeplot`:

```
bodeplot(sys)
```

The function `FREQZ` you intended to use is just for digital filters, not for transfer functions.

Finally you can test your model with Simulink:

[image]

where the numerator of the `Transfer Fcn` Block is `sys.num{1}` and the denominator `sys.den{1}` (for my example).

If the graph displayed in `Scope` (be aware that you should disable "Limit Data points to last 5000" in the scope Settings) is similar to your `outputdata` the estimation was successful.

---

I made a testrun for your model:  (fixed step solver, no continuous states, 0.0001 steptime).

[image]

Then the following code:

```
tfdata = iddata(inputdata,outputdata,0.0001);
N = 5;
sys = tfest(tfdata,N);
bodeplot(sys)
```

returning:

```
sys =

  From input "u1" to output "y1":

  -2068 s^4 + 2.89e06 s^3 + 7.017e10 s^2 + 5.205e13 s - 8.931e15

  -------------------------------------------------------

  s^5 + 1.034e04 s^4 + 4.552e07 s^3 + 1.114e11 s^2  + 8.337e13 s + 8.931e15
```

and:

[image]

or convert it to discrete:

```
sysd = c2d(sys,0.0001)

sysd =

  From input "u1" to output "y1":

  -0.0995 z^-1 + 0.4644 z^-2 - 0.7491 z^-3 + 0.5061 z^-4 - 0.1219 z^-5  

  -------------------------------------------------------

  1 - 4.042 z^-1 + 6.554 z^-2 - 5.332 z^-3 + 2.176 z^-4  - 0.3556 z^-5
```

I can't help you more, and it's a homework anyway, right? So the rest is up to you. And honestly, calculate it by hand! It will be much more exact!

Comment: Thanks for extensive reply, but I think we misunderstood. My simulink model contain a bunch of 1/z unit delays, sums and gains. 

So basically I have a digital filter and I need to plot a transfer function of this filter.

So the problem is how to run a Simulink model.mdl out of Matlab and then plot transfer function (which is easy).

Thanks

Comment: But how is that digital filter definded? Why can't you just use the properties of this filter and plot the transfer function with `FREQZ`? What do you need Simin/Simout for? Or do you want the transfer function of your whole model? Then you need to to what I wrote in my answer, with `tfest`. It would help if you extent your questions with some screenshots of your model. Instead of the errors which are very obvious and easy to fix.

Comment: I was given only the Simulink scheme. I also add screenshot of my model in my first post. Yes, I would like transfer function of my  whole model. Should I still use tfest?

Comment: I would calculate it by hand. And then check it with the result of `tfest`. I don't know if you could get trouble because it's a discrete model model. `tfest` will return a time continuous transfer function, but you can transform it later. I will edit my answer in a few minutes.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. It works perfectly!

Comment: How do you choose the number of poles to get the transfer function? I want to estimate the transfer function of my system but I dont know how to choose the poles before I get the transfer function. That just feels weird to me.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the error message should be self-explanatory: you haven't defined your variable `simin` in the base workspace. Define it (as a function of time) and then your model will run.

BTW, a much better way to obtain the transfer function from your Simulink model is use [`dlinmod`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/dlinmod.html), as other people have already pointed out, or [`linearize`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/slcontrol/ug/linearize.html) if you have Simulink Control Design. Your approach is prone to noise and not very robust. It also relies on your input having all the frequency components of interest, which is unlikely. Simulink Control Design also provides [`frestimate`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/slcontrol/ug/frestimate.html) to estimate the frequency response function of your model.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [dlinmod](http://www.mathworks.se/help/simulink/slref/dlinmod.html): Extract discrete-time linear state-space model around operating point (from a `Simulink` model).

Answer (score 0):

The following code helps me:

```
[A B C D]=linmod2('FileNameWithoutExtension');
tf_you_want_to_get=tf(minreal(ss(A,B,C,D)))
```